# Grid issue - Foundation

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I'm having a strange issue where the grid isn't size to my screen. When I use a large-12 column it's only taking up the middle of 1/3 of the screen, see the image. I'm not sure what is causing the issue. I don't have any weird CSS in place that should cause this happen. I'm not overriding the screen size anywhere, does anyone know why this would happen?

[image: Grid issue foundation]

I've disabled all the extra CSS that I added to isolate that as the issue.  Disabling it didn't seem to do anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Foundation the screen width is fixed for different media sizes. If the layout uses all 12 columns it does not mean it will occupy the whole width of the webpage, just the maximal width specified in `foundation.css`.

You can vary this by using the scss version or by creating a customized Foundation version on their webpage.